# java.lang.InterruptedException while executing Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

We use the library org.apache.http.client.HttpClient in accessing other web services from our web services.

```
HttpRequestBase requestBase = <set uri>
httpClient.execute(requestBase);
```

Now at certain times, this exception happens:

*

```
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Operation interrupted
    at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.await(PoolEntryFuture.java:142) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(AbstractConnPool.java:306) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$000(AbstractConnPool.java:64) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:192) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:185) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.get(PoolEntryFuture.java:107) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:276) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
```

*

Sometimes this this one shows up

*

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestAbortedException: Request aborted
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:193) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2045) ~
```

*

This happens intermittently. What could be causing this? need help on this. Will appreciate any advice I could get.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the http request is being aborted from the client-side.
Are you using any sort of thread pool executors in your code, that are submitting requests, and are being cancelled later for any reason (maybe slowness in response from thrid party )?